# Tools for auto update the android application apk

Tags: auto-update

I wanted to update my Android Application APK Automatically is there any external tool available to update the Android Application

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that some other external android application which updates your application on Device ? I don't think that is possible looking at application isolation and security in Android.

You will have to build update mechanism mechanism to update the application itself. (Unless you are publishing on Playstore

with some library like

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater
https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker